# Always the Latest google jQuery instead of default Wordpress jQuery

Tags: functions, jquery, performance

Im using  successfully the google CDN jQuery files instead of the built in files from Wordpress with the following code in my functions.php:

```
function register_jquery() {

    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');
        wp_register_script('jquery-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js', true, '2.2.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-core');

        wp_deregister_script('jquery-migrate');
        wp_register_script('jquery-migrate', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js', true, '1.2.1');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-migrate');

        wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
        wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', true, '1.11.4');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery' );
```

I think, advantages for using the google lib are the google CDN and the client side caching of the library.

**My Question:**

How can i change the code to load the latest jQuery Versions from Google automatically ?

Comment: You should properly indent your code, unfortunately your code is quite messy. Another note, it is not a good idea to enqueue your own copy of jquery. Also, why are you deregitering the scripts and reregistering them

Comment: I will read the wp docs... I found this code on a other coding site and it works for now. It would be awesome if you can provide me a better solution. Thank you so much

Comment: *It would be awesome if you can provide me a better solution* My response and way better solution would be to not use custom scripts loaded from outside of WordPress. Why do you need custom scripts in the first place

Comment: I think, advantages are the google CDN and the client side caching of the library

Comment: The disadvantage to always using latest is when it updates and breaks your site.

Comment: What if i use the WordPress.com Libraries like https://wordpress.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1 More trust then Google :)

Comment: How does that differ from google. wordpress.com and wordpress.org is two totally different things

Comment: if there is a way to get actual file from wordpress, i think the problem with breaking something should be gone...

Comment: you could use something like cloudflare. not quite the same, but would provide a performance boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Good Answer

The only good answer to this question is **don't do it** - simple as that.

Software in general expect things to work certain ways and libraries that are constantly evolving can have `breaking changes`. That means the change will cause another piece of software to stop working correctly which may be limited in scope or break all JS on the page.

---

[Google CDN](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery) does not have directory for `latest`.

> versions:
>
> 2.2.0, 2.1.4, 2.1.3, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.12.0, 1.11.3, 1.11.2, 1.11.1, 1.11.0, 1.10.2, 1.10.1, 1.10.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.0, 1.8.3, 1.8.2, 1.8.1, 1.8.0, 1.7.2, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.6.4, 1.6.3, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.0, 1.3.2, 1.3.1, 1.3.0, 1.2.6, 1.2.3

But you can reference the jQuery CDN - [`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) - although it is highly unadvised by jQuery based on their post - [`Don’t Use jquery-latest.js`](https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/)

> Earlier this week the jQuery CDN had an issue that made the jquery-latest.js and jquery-latest.min.js files unavailable for a few hours in some geographical areas. (This wasn’t a problem with the CDN itself, but with the repository that provides files for the CDN.) While we always hope to have 100% uptime, this particular outage emphasized the number of production sites following the antipattern of using this file. So let’s be clear: Don’t use jquery-latest.js on a production site.

### The Bad Answer

While everyone you talk to should tell you never to use `latest` in production, when you decide to throw caution to the wind just be sure to postfix your methods with `yolo`. This ensures that anyone looking at your code immediately recognizes that you're a rebel and sometimes you gotta break your site to make some omelettes.

Unfortunately, or fortunately depending on who you talk to, the rest of the libraries can't be referenced by `latest`.

```
function register_jquery_yolo() {

    // FIXME: This conditional should be removed:
    // if ( ! is_admin() ) {  

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-core' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js', true, 'latest-yolo' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-core' );

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-migrate' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-migrate', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.migrate/1.2.1/jquery-migrate.min.js', true, '1.2.1' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-migrate' );

        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-ui' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', true, '1.11.4' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui' );
    // }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_jquery_yolo' );
```

---

> I think, advantages for using the google lib are the google CDN and the client side caching of the library.

One BIG problem with using `latest` is that you don't actually want to cache the file because the url always needs to point to an up-to-date file. How else would you get the latest if it was cached?

---

> I still can't understand why anyone still uses if ( ! is_admin() ) when using wp_enqueue_scripts. It is totally useless with no purpose at all – Pieter Goosen

As was pointed out `if ( ! is_admin() )` should not be used in this case. [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is for front-end scripts, [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) for admin scripts, and [`login_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_enqueue_scripts) for login pages.

Comment: I still can't understand why anyone still uses `if ( ! is_admin() )` when using `wp_enqueue_scripts`. It is totally useless with no purpose at all

Answer (score 3):

One: Generally, *as pointed out in the comments,* this is a bad idea for your code, because things will break. https://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/

Two: There were once links to the "latest" jQuery libraries at the Google API - i.e., using the file name `jquery-latest.js` - but no more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608242/latest-jquery-version-on-googles-cdn

> We know that http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js is abused because
>   of the CDN statistics showing it’s the most popular file. That
>   wouldn’t be the case if it was only being used by developers to make a
>   local copy.
>
> We have decided to stop updating this file, as well as the minified
>   copy, keeping both files at version 1.11.1 forever.
>
> The Google CDN team has joined us in this effort to prevent
>   inadvertent web breakage and no longer updates the file at
>   http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js. That file
>   will stay locked at version 1.11.1 as well.